# Android xmlparsing and putting data in listview

Tags: android, listview, xml-parsing

I have two activity class of android. The main activity class contains xml parsing and i am trying to pass the data obtain from there to another activity class which is going to put it into listview of all the data. Below the is xml parsing main activity the problem is that, when I run the program it show nullpointer exception . I m stuck here can anyone help me where is the error . Thnx in advance

```
enter code here





/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(this);
        Intent i=new Intent(LocationSidActivity.this,FacebookData.class);
        i.putStringArrayListExtra("language", stringXmlContent);
        startActivity(i);
        // myXmlContent.setText(stringXmlContent);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


private ArrayList<String> getEventsFromAnXML(Activity activity)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    Resources res = activity.getResources();
    XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.myxml);
    xpp.next();
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            al.add(xpp.getName());
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            //if ((xpp.getName()).compareTo("id") != 0) {
                al.add(xpp.getName());
            //} else {
                //eventType = xpp.next();


        }

        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

            al.add(xpp.getText());
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
    }
    return al;

}
```

}

Comment: Put here your log error please. We need to know where is the null element to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The lines in your parser method `getEventsFromAnXML`:

```
if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
{
    al.add(xpp.getName());
}
```

may end up in a `NullPointerException`, because there is nothing read yet, and a **`null`** value will be added as the first member of your `ArrayList`.

The `XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT` in **API Docs**:

> Signalize that parser is at the very beginning of the document and
>   nothing was read yet. This event type can only be observed by calling
>   getEvent() before the first call to next(), nextToken, or nextTag()).

Also, if the `getEventsFromAnXML` method is in your `Activity` class, you should remove the parameter, and simply use **`this`**. It is never a good practice to share a `Context`, it will most often end up in leaks.